# In-text citation of book with year:page

Tags: biblatex, citing, biber, apa-style

I apologize if this question has been asked before, I wasn't able to find anything that exactly fit what I was trying to do. I'm attempting to change my citations in order to display the page number following the year and a colon. For example, I am using:

```
\parencite[27-45]{key}
```

And expecting to get the citation `(Dasgupta & Nino, 2009:27-45)`, but instead get `(Dasgupta & Nino, 2009, pp. 27-45)`.

I have tried using the `\cite{}` and `\citep{}` commands with various settings that I found while searching this site but to no avail.

A minimal working example that should demonstrate the problem appears below. I am using `babel`, `csquotes`, and `biblatex` with `style=apa`, and `biber` as a backend with the `natbib` compatibility option.

My `.tex` with all packages that I am using:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[english, american]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[%
    style=apa,backend=biber,natbib
    ]{biblatex}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{english}{american-apa}
\setlength{\parskip}{1em}
\addbibresource{./ref.bib}

\begin{document}

    \parencite[27-45]{immunological-computation}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

And an example from my `.bib` file:

```
@Book{immunological-computation,
    Title                    = {Immunological computation},
    Author                   = {D. Dasgupta and L. F. Nino},
    Publisher                = {CRC Press},
    Year                     = {2009},
    Place                    = {Boca Raton}
}
```

Any help with this would be appreciated, so thank you in advance.

Comment: Nice first question! Welcome! Note that you can use a `filecontents` environment before `\documentclass` to encapsulate a file needed for compilation. See the code in my answer for an example of how to do this. It makes it easy to provide a self-contained example which can be easily copied and pasted into a document.

Comment: Hi. Thank you very much for your help. I see that it's a duplicate question. Sorry about that. Ok, perfect. I will definitely use that in future. Thanks again all.

Comment: No problem. It is sometimes hard to find duplicates and a duplicate question serves as a pointer which may be useful to others. Sometimes I can't find questions even if I asked or answered them. The search function sucks.